# Function to permanently rename columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I am currently attempting to rename the columns in my dataframe, I have used the rename() function from the dplyr package :

```
physicians_table_raw %>%
  rename(
    year = Year,
    jurisdiction = Jurisdiction
)
```

In the console, the table returns with the column names changed.

However when I use the formula

`View(physicians_table_raw)`

The column names have not permanently been renamed.

Is there a function that will permanently rename the columns, I am worried that I will be using the incorrect column names by accident if it just keeps switching back to the original names.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you reassign it? `physicians_table_raw <- physicians_table_raw %>% rename(year = Year, jurisdiction = Jurisdiction)`. If you didn't, the renaming is just temporary.

Comment: Dplyr functions don’t change the value of of the objects you pass in, they return new values with updates properties (when using data frames or tibbles)